# Can I rewrite a key value while iterating a sync.Map using it's reciever function Range(func(key, value interface{}) bool {...})

Tags: go, hashmap, synchronization, range

I have the example below as the existing sync.Map (I know, they are iterfaces,this is just visualized) :

```
[1: "Hello", 2: "Good", 3: "Morning"]
```

Can I use the sync.Map's built in (reciever) Range function while iterating on it using to change the value of the keys based on certain conditions? Example:

```
sync.Map.Range(func(key, value interface {}) bool {
    if key.(int) == 1 {
        sync.Map.Store(1, "Sorry")
    }
    if key.(int) == 2 {
        sync.Map.Store(2, "Not")
    }
    if key.(int) == 3 {
        sync.Map.Store(3, "Interested")
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes, it's totally fine, `sync.Map` even supports concurrent modification, not just from your goroutine. Read the docs: _"Range does not necessarily correspond to any consistent snapshot of the Map's contents: no key will be visited more than once, but if the value for any key is stored or deleted concurrently, Range may reflect any mapping for that key from any point during the Range call."_

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. There's a lot of complex code that's gonna go inside that range function, so I didn't want to try implementing all of it it first & then realizing that it isn't supported or doesn't work as intended for my use case, so I wanted to a answer specific to my use case. @icza